# Package 'GuerrillaSharp 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I am trying to understand why the warning happens.

### Steps

1. Open Visual Studio 2019
2. Create new .NET Core class library. This is created with target framework .NET Core 2.1.
3. Add nuget package [GuerrillaSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GuerrillaSharp)
4. Build project

### Expected result

No issues or warnings.

### Actual result

> Warning   NU1701
>   Package 'GuerrillaSharp 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

### What I checked

I have found similar issues on Google/Stack Overflow, but don't see how this explains this nuget package situation. In many other posts the solution was often to install a newer version of the nuget package.

GuerillaSharp dependencies:

- Newtonsoft.Json (>= 11.0.2), which supports .NET Standard 1.0, 1.3 and 2.0. 
  So in my understanding, this should be compatible with .NET Core 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GuerillaSharp only has net461 binaries. There are many ways to check, but one way is to [view the package on fuget.org](https://www.fuget.org/packages/GuerrillaSharp). net461 is not "directly" compatible with netcoreapp2.1, but because so many package authors did not update their packages to support netstandard, the NuGet and .NET SDK teams added asset target fallback which basically says "well, net461 APIs are close to netstandard, so let's pretend it's compatible even though it might not be". That's why you're getting the warning. It might work, but if GuerillaSharp is using any .NET Framework-only APIs, it will crash at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the fuget.org tip! So if I understand correctly, this is not something you can see on nuget.org, right?

Comment: When the package author creates a dependencies section with groups and specifies their supported TFMs in those groups, nuget.org will show it under the dependencies section. But currently if the package author didn't give TFM information as dependency groups then no. There are common requests around target frameworks (not only showing, but also searching) and there are plans to improve the experience, but it hasn't yet reached the highest priority for an engineer to work on. However, we have an intern working on something that will be useful for this feature eventually.

Comment: Thanks, I logged an issue in the GuerrillaSharp repo https://github.com/NostraThomas99/GuerrillaSharp/issues/2